# Loop through a list of files with a specific MIME type in sh

Tags: shell, sh, dash-shell

I have a directory, and need to get a list of files with MIME types of `application/pdf`, which I can loop through and process with my `CompressPdf` function. The remaining files only need to be copied over the destination directory using `cp`, for which I need a loopable list as well.

The obvious obstacle is correctly handling UNIX filenames using `NUL`. So far I've come up with this:

```
find "dir-to-search" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file -0 --mime-type -F " " | grep -zZ "application/pdf"
```

But `grep` doesn't handle the results correctly because `file -0` inserts `NUL` right after the file name, with `\n` after the MIME information. It would return something like this:

```
0000000   .   /   f   i   l   e   1   .   p   d   f  \0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0000010   a   p   p   l   i   c   a   t   i   o   n   /   p   d   f  \n                                                                                                                                                                                      
0000020   .   /   f   i   l   e   2   .   p   d   f  \0                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0000030   a   p   p   l   i   c   a   t   i   o   n   /   p   d   f  \n
```

Another obstacle is that putting everything in one line limit the ability to use several lines of code with each iteration. Calling `xargs -I{} sh -c {}` inline will spawn a new process, which is unable to call my `CompressPdf` function. I am using Dash and `export -f CompressPdf` does not work. Executing `$0` recursively is my best bet.

Currently, my code is running well when processing several PDF files concurrently inside a single directory recursively. It prevents me from processing a large number of files at once, however.

Can someone help me with this? I'm trying to write in Dash instead of Bash for a little more performance, despite the fact that array is not available. I can switch to Bash if there is no other way.

Comment: `MIME types of application/pdf` is `find .. -name '*.pdf'` not enough?

Comment: @KamilCuk I thought of it before, but decided to rely on the MIME type instead of file name extension. That would leave a little freedom to use any, or even no extension. Although I highly doubt somebody ever uses other extensions for PDF files.

Comment: @oguzismail By piping commands one after another, I guess I'll end up with an `stdin` to be processed by `xargs -I{} sh -c {}`. With each file in the list, I want to do some other stuff such as condition checking, before actually compress it. And the sub `sh` process can't call the function from the parent process. `export -f` does not work in Dash.

Comment: @oguzismail I rely on the process pooling capability of `xargs -P`. With `find -exec` all files will be processed at once, which is not my expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 file -0 -0 --mime-type |
sed -z 'N;/\x00application\/pdf$/s///p'
```

So first from [man file](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html):

> -0, --print0
>
> If this option is repeated more than once, then file prints
>                just the filename followed by a NUL followed by the description
>                (or ERROR: text) followed by a second NUL for each entry.

So specify it twice.

Then I use `sed -z` to read zero separated stream two lines at a time. `-z` is a gnu extension to `sed`. If two zero separated lines end with `application/pdf`, then this matched string is removed and the filename is printed.

You can always work around zero terminated strings with `xxd`:

```
find . -type f -print0 |
xargs -0 file -0 -0 --mime-type |
# convert to hex
xxd -p -c1 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/00 /\n/g' |
# have filename and mime type on a single line
sed 'N;s/\n/00 /' |
# this is actually grep
# grep for application/pdf in hex
sed -n '/ 00 '"$(echo -n 'application/pdf' | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' | sed -r 's/(..)/\1\n/g' | paste -sd' ')"'/s// 00/p' |
# reverse the stream from hex to ascii
xxd -r -p
```

Comment: Your 2nd snippet with `xxd` works, but the 1st one prints out duplicate filenames (e.g: `file1.pdf\0file1.pdf\0`). Can you edit it? The sed commands and script are too complicated for me to comprehend in a short time.